# InvalidRegistration on sending push to muliple devices

Tags: php, android, firebase, push-notification

I'm trying to send push notifications to multiple device using Google Firebase and I always received the error : "InvalidRegistration".

This is the tokens that I sent in the "to"

```
 :json_encode($tokensPerEvent): 
 ["eV9g4oTwjZs:APA91bF3YLGtDkCDekvR6eahbVAn-jIY0sVGjxMWyBEyR-
  3AB9q6RBhw4fyeqE4ZkZxQs0TsYhUee9Txy_exAGxtrBPV_-
  sjKlWcV3z3nDYXOcVSVwlpPyGzUJKxGMU16drMR41bLI4t"]
```

and this is the response :

```
{  
   "multicast_id":***,
   "success":0,
   "failure":1,
   "canonical_ids":0,
   "results":[  
      {  
         "error":"InvalidRegistration"
      }
   ]
}
```

another questions: if the one of the tokens not exist anymore, this is effect on all the other tokens , or just the only old one will effected ?

This is my code:

```
<?php
    require_once '../CommonFunctions.php'; 

    ignore_user_abort();
    ob_start();

    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    //GET TOKENS FROM DB
    $db = new Database();
    $db->query("SELECT push_token FROM User");

    $db1 = new Database();
    $db1->query("SELECT phone FROM invite_list where event_id = 137");

    $response = $db->resultset();
    $response1 = $db1->resultset();

    $arr2 = array_column($response1, 'phone');
    $phones = join("','",$arr2);

    $db2 = new Database();   
    $db2->query("SELECT push_token FROM User WHERE phone IN ('$phones')");

    $tokensPerEvent = array();
    $tokensrr = $db2->resultset();
    $tokensPerEvent = array_column($tokensrr, 'push_token');

    echo json_encode($tokensPerEvent);    

    $fields = array('to' => json_encode($tokensPerEvent),
    'notification' => array('body' => 'HI', 'title' => ':)'));


    define('GOOGLE_API_KEY', '***********');

    $headers = array(
          'Authorization:key='.GOOGLE_API_KEY,
          'Content-Type: application/json'
     );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result === false)
    die('Curl failed ' . curl_error());
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to send push notification to many clients by theirs registration ids, you have to use **registration_ids** instead of **to** field. You can find this in [docs](http://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref) (second parameter).

---

You are also encoding tokens two times:

`$fields = array('to' => json_encode($tokensPerEvent), ...`

and

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));`

Try by skipping encoding `$tokensPerEvent` in array:
`$fields = array('to' => $tokensPerEvent, ...`

Comment: when i do that i'm received ->  Field "to" must be a JSON string: ******

Comment: @Yakir Okey... You want to send push notification to many clients by theirs registration ids?
Then you have to use `registration_ids` instead of `to`
You can find this in docs... i'l will try to find this, but I'm pretty sure this it is.
EDIT: Okey, I found it. Second parameter https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref

Comment: @Yakir Okay I will put in my answer.